# Moment returns wrong date for Unix timestamp

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to save unixtime to a state of type Moment.moment.
If you use moment(timestamp), you will get a different date.

```
  const [date, setDate] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(null);
  const timestamp = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);
  setDate(moment(timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You manipulated the date when you used `Math.floor`.

```js
console.log(moment());
console.log('With Floor', moment.unix(   Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() /1000 )));
console.log('Without Floor', moment.unix((new Date()).getTime() /1000 ));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Good Read: [You Don't Need MomentJS](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs)